# how to select all values by default of form_for select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In a form with form.select I want all options to be selected by default. I have age model, in form which is showing all ages I want to be selected all options by default. My code is following:

```
f.select(:age, options_for_select(Age.pluck(:age, :id) , :selected => @campaign.ages.pluck(:id)),{},{:multiple=>true , :required=>true})
```

Comment: In selected i am only selected id and i made multiple true due to which i can select multiple options. But issue is i want to be apear it as all selected options by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this through checks. If a user is created as a new record, then I selected all of them and in case of edit, I will only show only selected. As code following speaks of itself:

```
<% if @campaign.new_record? %>
  <%= f.select(:age, options_for_select(Age.pluck(:age, :id), :selected => Age.pluck(:id) ), {}, {:multiple => true,:required => true ,:class => 'form-control'}) %>
<% else %>    
  <%= f.select(:age, options_for_select(Age.pluck(:age, :id), :selected => @campaign.ages.pluck(:id) ), {}, {:multiple => true,:required => true ,:class => 'form-control'}) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f.select(:age, options_for_select(Age.pluck(:age, :id) , :selected => @campaign.ages.pluck(:id)),{:multiple=>true , :required=>true})
```

Comment: By doing this that field becomes single select. I want in multiselect all options to be selected by default.